# aarch64 worrying about memory barriers

Tags: assembly, memory, arm64

I've been trying to understand memory load/store ordering on aarch64, and I've been wondering whether memory barrier is necessary in this kind of code:

```
ldr x0, =0x9000
ldr x1, [x0]
orr x1, x1, #1   
/* is memory barrier (dmb) necessary here? */
str x1, [x0]
```

As far as I understood, CPU can reorder this so that str can be executed before ldr completes. Let's assume we have only one CPU core, so no SMP.

Comment: If you were right then [gcc would be broken](https://godbolt.org/z/j6M7WY).  Which is good reason to suspect that you're not right.

Comment: Have a look at the [Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0487/latest), B2.3.2 "Ordering and observability". The reordering you're describing is not allowed for a multitude of reasons.

Comment: Generally speaking, memory ordering is only about when stores made by one core will be seen by loads made by another core.  With no SMP the concept is irrelevant.  The CPU will arrange via caches or buffers that everything appears to a single-threaded program to be done in order, even if behind the scenes it does the actual reads/writes to memory in some other order.

Comment: Memory is always consistent with respect to the core your code is running on.  Memory barriers are only required when other threads asynchronously interact with your data (or in certain situations when writing device drivers or operating systems).

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I always thought it was relevant only for multiple threads / cores, but some texts (the reference manual being among them) confused me into thinking otherwise. :)